# java and C++11 volatile

Tags: java, c++, c++11, atomic, volatile

I'd like to port some piece of code from Java to C++11 and I'm a bit confused with volatile keyword.

I'm not familiar with Java language and I don't get what a volatile variable is. It guarantees that every thread has access to the up to date value of variable - it is the C++ volatile behaviour. But it is usually used to synchronize - are all actions performed on volatile variable atomic?

So I think thath the C++11 good replacement for Java volatile will be std::atomic. Or I'm totally wrong, cause I missed some additional Java volatile features?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they would be a good match, there is a good article on this at [Dr Dobbs](http://drdobbs.com/parallel/212701484).

> In a nutshell, ordered atomic variables are safe to read and write on
>   multiple threads at the same time without doing any explicit locking
>   because they provide two guarantees: their reads and writes are
>   guaranteed to be executed in the order they appear in your program's
>   source code; and each read or write is guaranteed to be atomic,
>   all-or-nothing.

Java provides this type of variable as `volatile`, C++ as `std::atomic`.

Comment: Lock-Free Thread Synchronization
Thread' volatile methods
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzDShvKbEMs#t=49m38s

Answer (score 1):

This page has a pretty nice explanation on Java's `volatile` keyword: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml.  It looks to me that C++11 `std::atomic<>` on primitive types (e.g., integers) indeed is a good replacement.  Note that `std::atomic<>` provides support for read-modify-write operations (e.g., `compare_exchange_strong` and `fetch_add`).